# Getting current MigrationId

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I want to get the "version" of the database i.e. the `MigrationId` of the last row in the `__EFMigrationHistory` table.

Since it's not possible to run raw SQL in Entity Framework Core without a `DbSet`, how can I get this information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In EF Core 1.1, you can use the following.

```cs
var currentMigration = dbContext.Database.GetAppliedMigrations().LastOrDefault();
```

Comment: I'm using 1.1 but I don't see the GetAppliedMigrations method on Database

Comment: @ghosttie Add `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`

Answer (score 2):

One option you have is to add the `__EFMigrationsHistory` table to your context. Create a model, something like this:

```
[Table("__EFMigrationsHistory")]
public class MigrationHistory
{
    [Key]
    [MaxLength(150)]
    public string MigrationId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(32)]
    public string ProductVersion { get; set; }

}
```

Add a `DbSet` to your model:

```
public DbSet<MigrationHistory> MigrationHistories { get; set; }
```

And now you can query the table as you would any other:

```
var lastMigration = context.MigrationHistories
    .OrderBy(mh => mh.MigrationId)
    .Last();
```